# using while loop inside ajax

Tags: php, ajax, while-loop

I'm trying to use a while loop inside in PHP And Ajax.

But I only get the First ID, not the 2nd, 3rd and so on.

Here is the code Of PHP:

```
<div class="container pt-5 my-5">
<section class="p-md-3 mx-md-5 text-center">
    <h2 class="text-center mx-auto font-weight-bold mb-4 pb-2">Our Team</h2>
    <div class="row">
        <?php while ($t_run=mysqli_fetch_array($t_query)){?>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 mb-4">
                <div class="p-4">
                    <div class="avatar w-100 white d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                        <input type="hidden" name="team" class='team_id' value="<?php echo $t_run['id']?>">
                        <img src='images/<?php echo $t_run['img']?>'class="team_img rounded-circle z-depth-1-half"/>
                    </div>
                    <div class="text-center mt-2">
                        <h6 class="font-weight-bold pt-2"><?php echo $t_run['name']?></h6>
                        <p class="text-muted">
                            <small><i><?php echo $t_run['title']?></i></small>
                        </p>
                        <button class="team btn-info border-0 p-2 rounded">View profile</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        <?php }?>
    </div>
</section>
```

and here is the Ajax code I use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
       $('.team').click(function (){
           var name = $('.team_id').val();
            $('#content_container').load('team-ajex.php',{
            id:name
            });
       });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: `$('.team_id').val()` will only get you the value of the _first_ element this finds in the whole document. You need to limit the scope of your selection, so that it gets the element that “belongs” to your specific button that was clicked. (For example by using a combination of `.parents()` and `.find()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd recommend you to try to change

```
$('.team_id').val()
```

to

```
$(this).parent().parent().find('input[name="team"]').val()
```

When you try to get `$('.team_id')` it returns an array of all inputs with this class...

Comment: Hi sir thank you very much I am new to PHP and always eager to learn new things

Comment: i'm glad that my answer helped you!

Comment: hi Is there any way to add new Fonts to TinyMCE editor I used the direct link